# Systemd shows inactive dead without errors

Tags: server, 18.04, systemd

I'm trying to config a service on Ubuntu 18.04 but the result is inactive (dead). This is my service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=asdfondi website
Documentation=https://github.com/riccardi1997/asdfondi
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=HOST=[hostname] DATABASE_URL=[database-url]
Type=simple
User=salr
ExecStart=/home/salr/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/bin/node /home/salr/asdfondi/s$
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the guide I'm following: https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/

And this is the result of `sudo systemctl status [service-name]`:

```
● asdfondi.service - asdfondi website
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/asdfondi.service; enabled; vendor preset:
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2022-11-27 08:28:14 CET; 13min ago
     Docs: https://github.com/riccardi1997/asdfondi
 Main PID: 10360 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 27 08:28:13 asdfondicalci systemd[1]: Started asdfondi website.
```

I'm blocked, for me everything is ok. Where am I wrong?

Sorry for the duplicated question, but the others are not helping me.

Comment: Your output shows systemd running the app/service successfully and completing what ever the task was. That suggests there is nothing in the task to continue doing such as listening on a port and processing any input. What happens if you take the command in the Execstart line and run it on the command line?

Comment: @PonJar it doesn't start because the exec cmd need environment variables but I declare them in service. So if the service start and export the environment variables I can also use them and start the exec cmd, right?

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I have to run npm start not the exec cmd above. Now the service is active (running)